# how to write procedure for the following in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

i have a tabel with columns as so..

```
column1     column2      column3    column4  column5
```

i want the datas to fill like below in column two..

where colum1,3,4,5...user will give the values...

in column2 its values should be auto sequencing like as follows...

```
column1     column2      column3    column4  column5
  1            1           one       one       one
  1            2          two       two       two
  1            3          three     three     three
  2            1          one       one       one
  2            2           two       two       two 
  2            3           three     three     three
  3            1           one       one       one
  3            2           two       two       two
  3            3           three     three     three
```

Folks kindly Give ur Suggestions...Thankxxx!!! cya!

Comment: Your question isn't clear about what you want this stored procedure to do.

Comment: I think he/she wants column two to be computed as 1,2,3 while the other columns are coming from the database.

Comment: Do you have some kind of unique key identifying the single entries?

Comment: What platform are you using?  MySQL, MS-SQL-Server, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to give each row a distinct value for equal values in column1. This can be done with a windowing function:

```
SELECT column1, 
       row_number() over (partition by column1) as column
FROM some_table
```

I do not understand what you want to have in columns3, 4 and 5

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your platform, the following May work...

```
UPDATE
  <your-table>
SET
  column2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1)
```

**EDIT**

As Martin says in his comment...

```
WITH
  windowed_table
AS
(
  SELECT
    column2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column1) AS row_number
  FROM
    my_table
)
UPDATE
  windowed_table
SET
  column2 = row_number
```

Comment: The OP is on SQL Server so would need `;WITH CTE AS (SELECT column2, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1) FROM <your-table> ) UPDATE CTE SET column2 = rn`